# SIM card: Detected when the card is removed

Tags: sim

I have an STM32 with a SIM card reader. For some reason the `DETECT` pin interrupt is triggered when the SIM card is *removed*, as opposed to when the SIM card is *inserted*.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: How is the detect signal generated?

Comment: "... why there aren't other answers.." should be read as "... **why/if** there aren't other answers..".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Possible reasons I can think of:

- the card detection switch switches from Vcc instead of ground, so that the logic is inverted and a falling edge becomes a rising edge and vice versa.
- there's contact bounce, generating both types of edges. Solved with an RC filter.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic logic inversion problem.

Could be that

- The signal from the card reader is the opposite polarity to what you expect (as also suggested by stevenvh)
- The micro is set up to respond to the opposite interrupt edge to what you expect
- There's a (maybe programmable) inverter within the micro between the pin and the IRQ logic
- There's an inverting buffer on the micro PCB between the SIM reader and the micro pin

---

Off-topic for the question, but is it required that you respond to that signal particularly quickly?  I'm not sure I see a need for an interrupt on that event, I would've thought just polling in the background loop would be sufficient.

Comment: The use of an interrupt instead of polling for detecting SIM card insertion has its merits: One avoids a polling loop that would very rarely yield results, wasting cycles the rest of the time. It isn't an uncommon requirement.